# Align divs in two column row css

Tags: css

I am trying to align two divs in each row by using float property, but problem is that when the content in all the divs are equal then everything word great. But as the content in divs goes more or less then div create blank space in between. Please suggest the changes I need to make in it so that even if div content goes more or less it does not create randam blank space. Also I need to use 100% width (not 30%+30%+padding).

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 20px;
  height: auto;
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1 ome demo test which can be shown</h2>
    <p>Some text.. here is some demo test which can be shown hereSome text.. here is some demo test which can be shown her which can be shown here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text.. here is some demo test which can be shown hereSome text.. here is some demo test which can be shown here</p>
  </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..Some text.. here is some demo test which can be shown hereSome text.. here is some demo test which can be shown here ere is some demo test which can be shown here test which can be shown here ere is some demo test which can be shown here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 5</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 6</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you don't like flexbox ?

Comment: sir please suggest me how to do it with flexbox

Comment: https://flexboxfroggy.com/ here is a way to learn flexbox

Comment: check I have created an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with flexbox.

```css
.row {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.column {
  flex : 0 0 49.5%;
  max-width: 49.5%;
  margin-bottom : 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing :border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1 ome demo test which can be shown</h2>
    <p>Some text.. here is some demo test which can be shown hereSome text.. here is some demo test which can be shown her which can be shown here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text.. here is some demo test which can be shown hereSome text.. here is some demo test which can be shown here</p>
  </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..Some text.. here is some demo test which can be shown hereSome text.. here is some demo test which can be shown here ere is some demo test which can be shown here test which can be shown here ere is some demo test which can be shown here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 4</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 5</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 6</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```